Cannot find 'preconditionIsolated' in scope in RealmSwift
Edited :
when my mac with Xcode 16 is stop working i used the older one with Xcode 14.3.1 to continue work but when i build project i face that error in realm-swift
I have Xcode 14.3.1 when build the project i found Error in RealmSwift and app want to run
I tried to some steps :

Pod deintegrate
Pod install
pod update realmSwift

but error Still appeared in Util.swift file in Realm swift Library

Well you need to update your Xcode, or use an older version of Realm.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

when my mac with Xcode 16 is stop working i used the older one to continue work but when i build project i face that error in realm-swift

preconditionIsolated is not available on Xcode 14. It is new in Xcode 16 if I remember correctly.
You can either

update Xcode, or
use an older version of Realm.

Looking at the commit history, this preconditionIsolated call is added on June 18 (5944cb0), and version 10.52.0 is released after that. A version earlier than 10.52.0 should compile just fine.

Ok thanks for help it helps me when uses version 10.52.0
